# Что берет inner в себе аргумент? обясните детально пжл

Tags: python, декоратор

```
def decorator(func):
    def inner(*args):
        start = timer()
        print(f"Function {func.__name__} starts its work")
        func(*args)
        end = timer()
        print(f"Function {func.__name__} took {end-start} time")

    return inner


@decorator
def something(a,b):
    time.sleep(3)
    print(a+b)
something(4,5)
```

Comment: Что значит "в себе аргумент"?

Comment: Во-первых: как-то изъясняйтесь яснее. Во-вторых: не надо плодить одни и те же вопросы.

Comment: @strawdog, ну, там все-таки про wraps, а тут про аргументы. Но нужно еще понять, что именно про аргументы)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция `inner` принимает все аргументы функции, в которой вы используете декоратор.
В вашем случае это 4 и 6.
Если вы не понимаете как это использовать попробуйте прочитать ниже.

#### Дополнение

Декоратор - это доп. функция которая запускается перед запуском основной функции.
Посмотрим на примере:

```py
def DopFunc(func):
    def local_func(*args):
        print("Все аргументы основной функции -", args)
        return func(args)
    return local_func

@DopFunc
def main(*args):
    print("Выполнение основной функции")

main(1,2,4,"2344r")
```

> Вывод:
> Все аргументы основной функции - (1, 2, 4, '2344r')
> Выполнение основной функции

Вот базовое применение декоратора, как видно `local_func` в `*args`
забирает все аргументы  функции `main`
Вообще есть два вида "особенных аргументов для функции" это `*args` и `**kwargs` отличия их в том что `*args` если видит елементи которые переданы функции но уже нет никакой свободной переменной в функции то он собирает из них массив.
А `**kwargs` применяется как словарь с ключом и значением.
Пример:

```py
def func(*args, **kwargs):
    print("args -",args)
    print("kwargs -", kwargs)

func("decorater", "class", "classroom", for_example="for_example", kwargs="args")
```

> Вывод:
> args - ('decorater', 'class', 'classroom')
> kwargs - {'for_example': 'for_example', 'kwargs': 'args'}

Comment: Для автора: Если ответ правильный поставьте зелёную галочку. Это означает что ответ правильный и он вам помог.